# SubInAcl tool: how to change permissions of a key containing a *

Tags: windows, registry, wildcard, command-prompt

I would like to change permissions of some registry keys using the tool subinacl.exe, but keys containing a star (the wildcard *) return an error:

> C:> subinacl /keyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT\*ISATAP /grant=%username%=F
>
> WARNING HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\Root\* : registry key i
>   s skipped (contains wildcard)

In this case, the message is repeated for every key starting with a wildcard under Enum\ROOT, but I want to modify only one key: Enum\ROOT\*ISATAP .

I tried passing the upper key object in combination of the /subkeyreg option and it gives the same error.

> C:> subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT /grant=%username%=F
>
> WARNING HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\Root\* : registry key i
>   s skipped (contains wildcard)

Is there a way to do this or is windows explicitely using a star to enforce permission changes to GUI tools like regedit ?

Thanks !